# Why this line of code doesn't need escaped quotes

Tags: php, escaping

I'm following a PHP tutorial, and came accross this line of code

```
redirect_to("manage_content.php?subject={$current_subject["id"]}");
```

I was surprised to see this works without the need to escape the quotes around "id" inside the brackets.

But I don't understand why.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you wrap a variable in curly braces `{}`, the PHP parser knows anything inside that is a variable and won't parse it like the rest of the string!

This only works with strings in double-quotes - single-quoted strings are taken at face value, so this has to be escaped:

```
$str = 'My cool string! {$array[\'key\']}';
```

While your example doesn't.

Because of this, it's best practice to put static strings in single quotes - it's a micro-optimization, but it's technically a bit faster since the PHP parser doesn't have to work its way through the string!

Comment: I'm actually not sure! It's been around as long as I've been writing PHP (since PHP 4). Read LOTS about strings here: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: though micro-optimization makes no sense in 99.9% cases ...+1 for curly braces  most of people just forgot about those :D

Comment: Yep - it's just a matter of code style most of the time. You're already running PHP - if you're trying to shave off nanoseconds, you've got some other things to consider :)

Comment: Thanks Jeff for your answer!